# NUMAnodes and SQL Server performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, vmware, numa

Pretty sure I understand this, but wanted to be sure I do.
We have a SQL Server 2016, that is running with 2 NumaNodes, each with 8 vCPUs.   The Max Degrees of Parallelism (MAXDOP) is set to 8.

This doesn't sound right to me.  First question:  Is that as bad an idea as I think it is?

From my research, I need to tell them to reduce the VM Settings to make this run in a single NUMANode.   We seem to be having random periods where queries that were running in 170 ms, are now timing out at 30+ seconds!   So, we do a quick look, and it is 5% CPU use, and low disk I/O use, and reasonable network use... Basically, the machine is about idle..  We also looked for queries waiting on locks, and there were none.  We are running the queries on the Secondary in a AG Group (a Read Only Query)

So, my guess:   It has gotten enough load that it switched and ran one the view in question (gets run about 4,000 times per day) on one of the vCPUs in the 2nd NUMANode, and then decided that execution plan should be always run on that node.   The result is that all the data it is accessing is cached in the other node's memory, and it needs to fetch it across the inter-node link (remote memory), so it does that, but that ends up being a lot slower (170 times?), and the queries are now all stacking up running more and more of them across this remote link... until it will always timeout because the remote memory is saturated...

Is that analysis valid?   I would hate to submit this as a solution to why the query suddenly jumps up in time if this is totally not correct.  And it will be hard to convince them they will get better performance with 8 CPUs than with 16.

Oh, additional evidence to back up my claim:  If I `select * into #tmp from myView OPTION (MAXDOP 16)` then I get a performance change of about -5% to -12% - meaning that it takes  longer to run the query than if I just used the 8 vCPUs.   However, not massively so.

So my question is:  Is there any validity to my analysis?

Update:   A couple other things, I got a lot of the information from: https://codenotary-compliance.medium.com/vmware-vsphere-why-checking-numa-configuration-is-so-important-9764c16a7e73

Secondly, If I do a `select * from sys.[dm_os_nodes]`  Then I get foreign_commited_KB as 5,414,260 or 5 GB, from the information above, that would sound like it is committed out of the other node which (is bad?)

Comment: You can post the actual execution plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/  Also you can examine the session wait stats for the session running the query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @TraderhutGames You should be able to get the failing query plan from Query Store, if you have it enabled. Since it only seems to be happening from the application, and not SSMS, give this a read: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: @ErikDarling   That last part about the Query Store is useful.   I've put in a request to enable this, 99% of my problem is getting the FAILING query plan, I can get the fast one, heck, run SSMS and I have one that takes almost no time at all.  (I've gotten it down to 25ms once), but right now, I'm having to push the view out and hope that it stops failing, which we were able to do on the query, but not the select COUNT_BIG(*) from theView, which is still timing out in over 30sec.    IF I can get this, I might be able to post the failing query plan, but if I get that It may be obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my question is: Is there any validity to my analysis?

No, not really. There absolutely is a (*very small*) performance penalty when doing cross-NUMA memory access. But that isn't the cause of your problems. The "performance penalty" is going to be a small percentage, not a massive 170x increase.

If you are looking at a slow query, you should start by reviewing that query for performance issues. Indexing & good old-fashioned performance tuning might get you a 170x improvement, but NUMA configurations won't get you very far.

> Secondly, If I do a select * from sys.[dm_os_nodes] Then I get foreign_commited_KB as 5,414,260 or 5 GB, from the information above, that would sound like it is committed out of the other node which (is bad?)

The `sys.dm_os_nodes` DMV is proof that SQL Server is NUMA-aware. SQL Server knows what's going on with the server you're running it on, and it will handle things itself.

VMware has created [a white paper](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf) related to configuration considerations for running SQL Server on VMs. Note that Section 3.6 on pages 27-39 discusses NUMA in depth.

That said--it sounds like your problem is that a query is slow. I don't see any evidence in your question that points to NUMA being the reason behind it. Your best bet would be to start at the beginning with basic performance tuning of the query. The comment from [Erik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/erik-darling) is good advice on how this community has found to be an effective way for us to help you. If, after going through query-tuning steps, you are not able to improve performance, you can post a new question following Erik's suggested guidelines:

> If you want help with the view, please follow this advice: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/).

Comment: Very Helpful answer, with links and useful info, but the ending...:-(  so I need the query to run in under 15 seconds (15,000 ms) or so, it is currently running in 170ms, I have optimized it to improve the performance by 30%.   However, sometimes, under our app ONLY (except once), it starts timing out at over 30 seconds.   You say I should post the Execution plan of the query that is working fast, and all the tables/joins and indexes, so we can drop that 170ms down to?   How do I know when I'm done?  Push to prod, wait 4 days and see if it it times out again?

Comment: I can't really say without knowing more about the query, plan, and wait types. But with regard to this question specifically, everything you describe sounds like a performance tuning issue. Erik's given some great pointers in the comments on your question. But you may need to open a new question to attack the specific query, including an article directly about queries being fast in SSMS, but slow in the app

Comment: FYI: The 'correct answer' had to do with running a query to get running queries, which included showing the execution plan handle, grabbing that handle (in the latest SSMS) and doing a query for just that handle, which included showing the execution plan, and looking at it, which showed me what I was thinking might be the issue (but hard to know without seeing the plan), where it was doing several lazy spools (because, it was only 4 rows, not the 250,000 rows it would be with a different parameter),   I have several options now on fixes for this.  And can now duplicate the problem

Comment: (Oh, I guessed how to duplicate the problem, or would not have been able to get the plan this way for another some number of days.. I had to guess the parameter that was being badly sniffed..)  - The most useful thing was the info on the Query Store, and if I can get that turned on, plus other links.  Most useless (to me) was all the messages about Upload your Plan! Here is how to ask your question! (etc), and the down vote was encouraging me to delete the question...)

Comment: @TraderhutGames, the comments asking for plans & other info for the query were all trying to point you in the right direction---away from the question that you asked, which was about NUMA--towards looking into the specific problematic query. There were no details in the question about the query, making it impossible to help you with the real problem.  You can always raise a question on [Meta] about how the community runs the site & how/why folks responded the way they did.

Comment: I get that, but if someone asks a question without an execution plan, and is asking about something else, I.E. Does this cause massive performance issues like I've been told?  Downvoting the question because it doesn't have a plan, or because the person hasn't uploaded one yet, doesn't make the *question* bad, the question should be valid (with an answer of No, *and* with why like you @amTwo did.) is helpful.   I posted a while ago (on the same issue actually), and got double down voted and I deleted the question!  (Instead of adding more details/pursuing the solution there..) - Just not nice